# PHP: MySQLi query returns false with null error when running cronjob via CLI, but works if call script via Web server

Tags: php, mysqli, cron

This script has been working fine for years and still does work fine in certain circumstances but I am trying to validate another circumstance but it is failing without any error messages.

I have been struggling with this all day now and am at a dead end.

I use the following with 3 x email inboxes - I check for an email, use the details in the subject to validate the customer and then set the customer object before inserting email contents against customer.

This has been and still does work fine for the existing 2 mailboxes however, the 3rd (new mailbox) just keeps failing at `$this->mysqli->query($query)` returning false.

It is extracting the email correctly as I can see by outputting the email subject - it has it, it has read it, it has correctly built the SQL query... It just wont execute successfully...

```
        //Build the query
    $query = "SELECT id, 
                     parent_id, 
                     name, 
                     storeno,
                     make,
                     active_advisors,
                     address,
                     primary_contact,
                     primary_phone,
                     primary_email,
                     secondary_contact,
                     secondary_phone,
                     secondary_email,
                     daily_email_receipients,
                     wty_analysis_email_recipients,
                     created,
                     expiry,
                     modified,
                     modified_by,
                     active,
                     customer_type
              FROM Customer
              WHERE LOWER(name) = LOWER('".addslashes($emailHeader['customername'])."')
                AND LOWER(storeno) = LOWER('".$emailHeader['storeno']."')
                AND LOWER(make) = LOWER('".$emailHeader['make']."')";

        //debug query
        print $query;

        //Execute the query and validate that it was executed without issue
        if( $result = $this->mysqli->query($query) ) {

            //Print row count for debugging
            print "Select returned ".mysqli_num_rows($result)." matching rows for 'Customer' lookup.";

            //Check to see if we got what we expected (an single exact match!)
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result)==1) {

                //Transfer the result into a usable Object
                while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {

                    $this->setCustomerInformation($row);
                }
            }

            // If we get 0 then we have no match
            // If we get > 1 then we have a problem (and still no match)
            else { 

                print "Could not match email details to a customer: (".implode(",",$emailHeader).")"; 
                return false;
            }

        }
        else { 
            print 'Mysqli Query returned false: " ('.serialize($this->mysqli).')';
            print mysqli_errno($this->mysqli);
            print mysqli_error($this->mysqli);
            return false;
        }
```

Outputs:

```
SELECT id, 
                     parent_id, 
                     name, 
                     storeno,
                     make,
                     active_advisors,
                     address,
                     primary_contact,
                     primary_phone,
                     primary_email,
                     secondary_contact,
                     secondary_phone,
                     secondary_email,
                     daily_email_receipients,
                     wty_analysis_email_recipients,
                     created,
                     expiry,
                     modified,
                     modified_by,
                     active,
                     customer_type
              FROM Customer
              WHERE LOWER(name) = LOWER('XXXXXXXX')
                AND LOWER(storeno) = LOWER('S01')
                AND LOWER(make) = LOWER('FO')

Mysqli Query returned false: " (O:6:"mysqli":19:{s:13:"affected_rows";N;s:11:"client_info";N;s:14:"client_version";N;s:13:"connect_errno";N;s:13:"connect_error";N;s:5:"errno";N;s:5:"error";N;s:10:"error_list";N;s:11:"field_count";N;s:9:"host_info";N;s:4:"info";N;s:9:"insert_id";N;s:11:"server_info";N;s:14:"server_version";N;s:4:"stat";N;s:8:"sqlstate";N;s:16:"protocol_version";N;s:9:"thread_id";N;s:13:"warning_count";N;})
```

What I have done so far:

1. I have output $query and run it in MySQL and it successfully returns a correct result
2. I have compared the mysqli object on all 3 mailbox checks and they are identical
3. I have run the process with a mail in every inbox (first 2 = success) and 3rd fail
4. I have run the process with only a mail in the 3rd mailbox = failed (thinking maybe I was resetting the connection)

I have run out of ideas - to test and dont know where to go

**The error output is NULL**

Additional test - this process is running via cron job - I have just run the process manually through a browser and it works...

- PHP version in browser and cli are the same
- Mysqli Objects are identical in Browser and CLI
- mysqli->Query() result is different:

CLI:

```
NULL
```

Browser:

```
mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 
    [field_count] => 
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 
    [type] => 
)
```

Just discovered, mysqli->stat()

CLI: NULL
Browser: Populated

Clearly there is an issue with MySQLi object

Comment: You've identified that the problem lies with running the SQL query, but your question doesn't include the query, error number or error message? Can you include this information in your question.

Comment: And you are sure it pulling the data you expect from the actual mailbox,  `1` above is a given, if the query runs for 2 out of 3 calls then the query is obviously not the problem,  But are you preparing you SQL, or just injecting data into it.  You can get all kinds of issues if you have things like quotes etc, that are not escaped, without seeing how you put the query together all one can do is guess, because this is not a testable question.  If the query is fine then it must be the data...

Comment: Another example `$emailHeader['make'] = "thing's"` that single quote will kill your SQL query.  aka `LOWER(make) = LOWER('thing's')`

Comment: I added the $query - it is not prepared, just a normal SQL query. I am absolutely positive it is pulling the correct data from the actual mailbox - have been testing and validating all day. I am using print $query - then copying that and pasting directly into MySQL with expected results...

Comment: @php-b-grader - If the query was working, `query()` wouldn't return `false`. What is the MySQL error?

Comment: @fubar - see title: returning false with null error - there is no error

Comment: Ok, so this query is running via cron and failing.  I just ran it manually through a browser and it worked fine. It is the cron that returns a false result...

Comment: what if any output do you get you have a few `print` calls in there, do they output anything, specially the ones in the `else` conditions.  (PS I haven't used print in about 8 years ... ha ha)

Comment: Are your PHP versions and `ini` configurations identical for both the CLI and server module versions of PHP?

Comment: PHP versions are the same and the only web ini overrides are session.gc_maxlifetime = 7200
session.cookie_lifetime = 14400

Comment: If you print the prepared queries when run via the browser and from the cron, is there a difference?

Comment: Exactly the same SQL queries

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here to be able to help further. We'd just be guessing. I'd suggest you perhaps look into the differences between MySQLi in the different PHP versions you're using.

Answer (score -1):

Try to call `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL)` before querying the data. It enables or disables internal report functions.

[mysqli_report on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php).

Also I suggest not to mix object oriented and procedural style of [PHP: MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) library.